# Swift pass data between VCs

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

i'm new to Swift and i would like to know why this piece of code i translated from Obj-C doesn't work here.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "scoreDetail" {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject

            let itemVC: ScoreVC = segue.destinationViewController as ScoreVC
            itemVC.detailItem = object
        }
    }
```

Here is the storyboard. I have a `Show Replace` segue from the cell to the `UINavigatorController`
[image]

I get this error as soon as i click on a `UITableViewCell`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Swift. The destinationViewController is the navigation controller, not your ScoreVC, so the code you translated that from shouldn't have worked either (if it had the same setup). It should look like this,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "scoreDetail" {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject

            let nav : UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController
            let itemVC: ScoreVC =  nav.topViewController as ScoreVC
            itemVC.detailItem = object
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are totally right i just noticed this thing! Thank you very much